# android - Issues with moving and rotating ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm investigating how to interact with objects on the screen with a simple app:

I have one `ImageView` which can be moved with one pointer and rotated using a second pointer. 
When the view is touched it slightly increases in size and returns to original size on release. 
I have 2 issues with this app:

- when rotating it doesn't behave correctly crossing the 0° and 180°;
- after being released the image gets cropped.

I don't know if this can be easily solved or i'll need to completely change my approach, but any help/tips are greatly appreciated.

here's my code:

main.xml is an empty RelativeLayout.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ImageView image;
ViewGroup group;
int oldX, oldY;
static float x1,y1, degrees, width,height;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams startLayoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);
    image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.androids);//set image(80x80px)
    image.setOnTouchListener(touch);
    startLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        startLayoutParams.leftMargin = 50;
        startLayoutParams.topMargin = 50;
        startLayoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
        startLayoutParams.rightMargin = -250;

    image.setLayoutParams(startLayoutParams);
    group.addView(image);   

}//end onCreate


public OnTouchListener touch = new OnTouchListener() {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams downParams, upParams, moveParams;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.android);//set slightly larger image(100x100px)

                downParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    downParams.leftMargin = downParams.leftMargin-10;//adjust margin to compensate for larger image
                    downParams.topMargin = downParams.topMargin-10;
                    downParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    downParams.rightMargin = -250;

                view.setLayoutParams(downParams);

                oldX = X - downParams.leftMargin;//get starting position
                oldY = Y - downParams.topMargin;

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.androids);//Reset smaller image

                upParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    upParams.leftMargin += 10;//re-adjust margin
                    upParams.topMargin += 10;
                    upParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    upParams.rightMargin = -250;

                view.setLayoutParams(upParams);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:

                x1=event.getX(1);// get starting coordinates for calculating degrees to rotate
                y1=event.getY(1);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                int pointer         = event.getPointerId(0);
                int pointerCount    = event.getPointerCount();

                moveParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    moveParams.leftMargin = X - oldX;//get new position
                    moveParams.topMargin = Y - oldY;
                    moveParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    moveParams.bottomMargin = -250;

            if (pointerCount == 1) {//move image

                view.setLayoutParams(moveParams);

            }else if(pointerCount == 2){//move and rotate image

                for(int i = 0 ; i<pointerCount;i++){

                    if(event.getPointerId(i)==pointer){

                        view.setLayoutParams(moveParams);//move

                    }//end if

                }//end for

                degrees = getDegrees(event);
                width = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable().getBounds().width();
                height = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable().getBounds().height();

                Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
                ((ImageView)view).setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
                matrix.postRotate(degrees, width/2, height/2);//rotate
                ((ImageView)view).setImageMatrix(matrix);

            }//end if-else if

            break;

        }//end switch-case

        group.invalidate();

        return true;

    }//end onTouch

};//end OnTouchListener touch

public static float getDegrees(MotionEvent event){

    float x0,y0, x2,y2, A,B,C, angle,cosa;

    x0 = event.getX(0);
    y0 = event.getY(0);
    x2 = event.getX(1);
    y2 = event.getY(1);

    A =  FloatMath.sqrt(sq(x0-x1) + sq(y0-y1));
    B =  FloatMath.sqrt(sq(x0-x2) + sq(y0-y2));
    C =  FloatMath.sqrt(sq(x2-x1) + sq(y2-y1));

    cosa = (sq(A)+sq(B)-sq(C))/(2*A*B);
    angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(cosa));

    return  (x0<=x2) ? angle : opposite(angle);

}//end getDegrees

private static float sq(float input){

    return (float) Math.pow(input, 2);

}//end square

private static float opposite(float value){

    return value-(2*value);

}//end opposite
}//end MainActivity
```

I realise there's many questions on this subject and i've read dozens of them and tried several of them out, but the issues persisted or other ones arose, hence I decided to post this question.

info on the getDegrees():

I can't post images so check: http://i50.tinypic.com/vsjl28.jpg

- p0 =(x0,y0) = the current position of the *first pointer*
- p1 =(x1,y1) = where the *second pointer* is first put down
- p2 =(x2,y2) = the current position of the *second pointer*

getDegrees() returns the *angle c* if second pointer is on the right sight of the first pointer the *negative value of c* when on the left side of it.

Comment: if i am not wrong you want to drag and scale if yes then have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

Comment: Not scaling, although i want the selected item to enlarge slightly when selected, it's mainly about rotating and moving the image.(I'll check it out anyways)

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the angle between CA and CB. As the angle passes 180 degrees, the triangle ABC would then be on the other side of the line CA. Thus, the angle would just begin to decrease again until you get back to CA=CB where the angle is zero again.

I'm afraid I can't really suggest another way of doing it because I don't understand exactly how you want the triangle to rotate in relation to the touch input.

Comment: The triangle is to determine the angle at which the ImageView gets rotated. I've edited my post elaborating on it. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Maybe instead of returning the negative angle if it's on the left side, you could return 360 minus the angle.